# Get date when a cell is filled only when it says "Yes"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to change to get the date when column B is updated with the word "YES" only.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "EXPORTACION") { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if (r.getColumn() == 2) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column B
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if (nextCell.getValue() === 'YES') //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask],

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="EXPORTACION" && e.range.columnStart==2 && e.value=="YES") { 
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```